# Django models - how to map specific subgroup clusters to their exclusive mother groups

Tags: django, django-models

I have got 2 database tables I would like to model in Django

The first table is named Groups and is limited to 7 specific choices, A B C D E F G. I've done that.

The second table is named Subgroup and is limited to 39 specific choices, numbered 1 to 39, in clusters of different sizes. Each cluster should map to only one specific group. I can't move here.

How do I set up the second model to reflect the relationship so that whenever a user chooses, say subgroup option 8, the correct foreign key used refers to B in the example, or whenever choosing subgroup option 29 the foreign key used refers to F? It should be impossible to map subgroup 15 to group G, for example.

Assume the mapping should be:
A:  1- 5, B:  6-13, C: 14-16, D: 17-20
E: 21-26, F: 27-30, G: 31-35 and H: 36-39